# How can I find the amount of numbers in double?

Tags: c++, floating-point, double

Let's say I have an input `1.251564`.

How can I find how many elements are after `"."` to have an output as follows:

```
int  numFloating;

// code to go here that leads to
// numFloating == 6
```

p.s. Sorry for not providing any code, I just have no idea how that should be implemented :(

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: How many elements after the dot are in the number 1/3 ? Mathematically speaking, in decimal base, there are an infinite 3's after the dot. I am not sure how this number will react if multiplied by 10 (for example) and obviously, you can't store the number infinity. It's not a simple question, because the representation and manipulation of floating point values don't allow this.

Comment: Let's consider we have double type - which means we have max 16 elements after dot.

Comment: I reverted the edit. When you have a new question to ask, you need to ask it as such, a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't end up well. The problem is that sometimes there are float errors when representing numbers in binary (which is what your computer does). 
For example, when adding 1 / 3 + 1 / 3 + 1 / 3 you might get 0.999999... and the number of decimal places varies greatly.

ravi already provided a good way to calculate it, so I'll provide a different one:

```
double number = 0; // should be equal to the number you want to check
int  numFloating = 0;
while ((double)(int)number != number){
    number *= 10;
    numFloating++;
}
```

number is a double variable that holds the number you want to check for decimal places.

Comment: Thanks, could you please clarify what the "number" is? The input?

Comment: With `double number = 1.251564`, this code results in `numFloating == 0`

Comment: This doesn't work even in principle, because multiplication by 10 is not exact.

Answer (score 5):

Let us consider your number, `1.251564`. When you store this in a `double`, it is stored in the binary IEEE754 format. And you might find that the number is not representable. So, let us check for this number. The [closest representable](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=1.251564) double is:

```
1.25156 39999 99999 89880 45035 73046 53152 82344 81811 52343 75
```

This probably comes as something of a surprise to you. There are 52 decimal digits following the decimal point.

The lesson that you need to take away from this is that if you want to ask questions about decimal representations, you need to use a decimal data type rather than `double`. Once you can actually represent the value exactly, then you will be able to reason about it in a manner that matches your expectations.

Comment: Thanks, good to know that. The issue that I want to solve is to see if the double number in form of prime fraction has odd denominator.

Comment: That's a nice link. I love how 0.1 isn't really 0.1 :)

Comment: @MikaelEgibyan Then why didn't you ask "How do I determine if the double number in form of prime fraction has odd denominator"?

Comment: @MikaelEgibyan Your fundamental issue relates to how you represent your data. Using a binary format is going to be the wrong choice.

Comment: I wanted to solve the rest by my self, but I will update the question now.

Comment: I don't see any reason to change the question. It was well posed. If you want to ask a different question ask a new one.

Comment: I got "-3" for this question and I can't ask now (((

Comment: That seems a little off. Do you just have to wait? Anyway, what about this question? Do you need more help understanding?

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way would be to store it in string.

```
std::string str("1.1234");
size_t length = str.length();
size_t found = str.find('.', 0 );
size_t count = length-found-1;
int finallyGotTheCount = static_cast<int>(count);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And then if I want to take that number as an integer, how can I convert it?

Comment: Thanks, that explained the answer well. Unfortunately I will like to avoid using std standards like :string: as I am working on a cross platform, but thanks much!

Comment: @MikaelEgibyan That last comment makes no sense at all. Everything in this answer is cross platform. The standard library is, well, standard.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fractional number. Lets say .1234

Repeatedly multiply by 10 and throw away the integer portion of the number until you get zero. The number of steps will be the number of decimals. e.g:

```
.1234 * 10 = 1.234
.234 * 10 = 2.34
.34 * 10 = 3.4
.4 * 10 = 4.0
```

Problems will however occur when you have a number that is "floating" like 1.199999999.

Answer (score 0):

```
int  numFloating = 0;

double orgin = 1.251564;

double value = orgin - floor(orgin); 

while(value == 0)
{
   value *= 10;
   value = value - floor(value); 
   numFloating ++;
}
```

By using this code sometimes answer is wrong. exp: zero in floating point is equal to (2^31)-1.
Obviously output depends on how it realy stored.

Comment: Thanks that should fit me, because I don't need to convert it :)